# Running Command Line Arguments

Tags: vb.net, shell, command-line, cmd

I'm trying to run a command line argument through VB.NET using the Shell() command.

I'm trying to use this piece of code:

```
FOR /R %I in (*.pdf) DO @pdf2swf.exe "%~fI" -o "%~dpI%~nI.swf" -f -T 9
-t -G
```

Using this:

```
Shell("FOR /R %I in (*.pdf) DO @pdf2swf.exe "%~fI" -o "%~dpI%~nI.swf" -f -T 9
-t -G ")
```

However, the interpreter is giving me this error:

```
Character is not valid. (BC30037)
```

For the `%~` part.

I also tried created a string and passing the argument to the Shell() command by using `Shell(StringName)` but I still get the same error in the string.

How could I fix this issue?

Comment: you need to escape your internal quote marks

Comment: I tried it but the program still crashes on that line

Comment: @Jodrell `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: File not found.`

Comment: @Brian - that's a new error then, and fairly self-explanatory, I think.

Comment: @Tim Yes but what file does it need if its a command line argument? Also, pdf2sfw.exe is in the folder.

Comment: @Tim No, but before the `Shell(args)` command I put `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dlgFolder.SelectedPath)` to set the current path to the selected folder.

Comment: @Brian - and dlgFolder.SelectePath is where pdf2sfw.exe is at?  (Just making sure, since there's potentially two file paths here - one for pdf2sfw.exe and one for the *.pdf).

Comment: @Tim Yes. That as such is no problem as I can insert code to copy the pdf2sfw.exe and put it in the selected path and delete it afterwards. However, to test the command out, I put pdf2sf.exe in the folder manually. So yeah, the .exe is there

Comment: @Brian: Good to know! I've moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try escaping the quotes (2 quote marks - "" - in VB.NET, IIRC):

```
Shell("FOR /R %I in (*.pdf) DO @pdf2swf.exe ""%~fI"" -o ""%~dpI%~nI.swf"" -f -T 9 -t -G ")
```

If pdf2swf.exe is not in the same folder your program's executable is running from, that could be a reason you're getting the error.

Also, you'll have the same issue with the *.pdf files if they are in a different folder other than where your executable is.  You can specify the drive and path to search:

```
Shell ("FOR /R C:\SomeFolder %I in (*.pdf) DO @pdf2swf.exe ""%~fI"" -o ""%~dpI%~nI.swf"" -f -T 9 -t -G ")
```

Comment: No no, it just crashes on that line. `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: File not found.`

Answer (score 2):

This is not proper use of the [Shell Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.shell.aspx):

> `Public Shared Function Shell (PathName As String, [...]) As Integer`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *PathName*
>     Type: System.String
>     Required. String. Name of the program to execute, together with any required arguments and command-line switches. PathName can also include the drive and the directory path or folder.

The first parameter is supposed to be the name of a program to execute. `FOR` is not a program, it's a built-in feature of the `cmd.exe` command line interpreter.

As far as I can see, you have the following options:

**Option 1**: Explicitly call `cmd.exe` and pass the string that you want to execute with the `/c` parameter:

```
Shell("cmd.exe /c for /R %I ...")
```

Don't for get to duplicate quotation marks (`"`) to escape them.

**Option 2**: Create a batch file and call the batch file using `Shell`.

**Option 3**: Don't use `FOR` to find the files you need, but use the methods of the System.IO namespace, e.g. [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx), instead.

Comment: good answer (epecially the part about explictily calling cmd.exe).  Hopefully the OP will accept your answer (and deaccept mine) when he logs on again.

Answer (score 1):

Escape your internal quote marks like this.

```
Shell("FOR /R %I in (*.pdf) DO @pdf2swf.exe ""%~fI"" -o ""%~dpI%~nI.swf"" -f -T 9 -t -G ")
```

As I recall, in VB.Net you escape double quote marks by doubling them.

**EDIT:**

It might help if you do the iteration outside of the Shell. (Certainly to debug)

```
Dim sourceFolder As String = "c:\Your call"
Dim sourceFiles As String[] = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, "*.pdf")

ForEach file As String In sourceFiles
    Dim justName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
    Dim shellCall As String = _
        String.Format("pdf2swf.exe ""{0}"" -o ""{1}.swf"" -f -T 9 -t -G", _
                         file, justName)
    Shell(shellCall)
EndFor
```

You could also cosider using `System.Diagnostics.Process` instead of `Shell`

Comment: So, whats the new error, or maybe even question? At least it now compiles.

Comment: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: File not found.`

Comment: @Brian, at least one of the files you are working with is not found.

Comment: @Brian, rather than doing the iteration in the shell (where it is hard to debug) why dont you get the file names in VB and then iterate the shell calls there?

Comment: Can you kindly explain more easily? I'm trying to use that command line argument, because basically, it's easer (in my opinion) since it just takes all the PDF files in the folder and converts them to PDF and then renames them to their original name.